# rsync: how will rsync react to a file copy from a mounted share to a remote location?

Tags: cron, rsync, mount

I have a task to create a passive sync between a production server and a staging server which are 
located in two different geographical locations.

The environment is fully Linux based (CentOS/RHEL) and the size of the data to be synced is about 1.5GB per day and only once per day.

The method I chose is `rsync`.

The source directory to sync resides on a CentOS database server called 'pg4' which has a NFS mounted share to another server in the same LAN, let's refer to this other server as 'mass1'.

My idea was to create a `cron` job of `rsync` on 'mass1' and to push the files from there to the target server around the globe on a line which is capable for the task.

The DBA which gave me this task insists that the `rsync` `cron` job should be configured straight on the database server 'pg4' rather than on the server where the data is but the one which holds the mount to the folder to sync.

My question is:

Will `rsync` copy the data first to the 'pg4' server and then to the target server if I configure the `cron` job there? or will it do the `rsync` straight from the 'mass1' server?

I would think that logically, configuring the `cron` job on 'mass1' server would be the right way to do it, what do you think?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand is your situation:

Data is on `pg4` and should go to server `remote`. You have the directory with the data mounted via NFS on `mass1`.

This is what will happen:

- If you run the `rsync` on `mass1`, e.g. `rsync -av /mnt/pg4/data user@remote:/data`, the data will be copied per NFS to `mass1` and then copied to `remote` via `rsync`.
- If you run the `rsync` on `pg4` directly to `remote`, eg. with `rsync -av /data user@remote:/data`, it will not be copied to another server but to `remote` directly.
- `rsync` can't copy with both ends being remote, so `rsync -av user@pg4:/data user@remote:/data` on `mass1` won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My idea was to run on `mass1` `rsync -av local_path user@remote:/date` but your second point answers my question.
Will any of the methods affect the speed of the transfer?

Comment: @ItaiGanot Depending on your infrastructure NFS speed will most likely rank in the 100Mbit speed range. Your upload speed will probably rank in the low 10Mbit speed range. Chances are your upload speed is such a major bottleneck compared to the local copying that you won't notice much difference on a 1,5GB sync.